# Load CSS and JS using absolute paths on select pages

Tags: 7, javascript

I've got a page (menu callback) which serves as a template for an external service. As the HTML of the page is consumed by the external service and rewritten then served from their server, all the CSS and JS paths must be absolute. Elsewhere on my site I use relative paths via AdvAgg, but here I need to rewrite all the link elements to be of the type `file`, rather than type `external`.

How can I do this? I have tried doing a `hook_css_alter` or `hook_js_alter` and changing type to `external` and prefixing the `data` value with my site's base URL but it doesn't seem to be making my AdvAgg aggregate files absolute, their paths stay relative.

Another idea I had was iterating through all the site's CSS files and unsetting the local entries and instead calling `drupal_add_js` or `drupal_add_css` but referencing the files as `external` with an absolute path, but I don't know where I would do this.

I'm using Drupal 7 with CSS and JS aggregation turned on and with the AdvAgg module enabled.

Comment: `I don't know where I would do this.` me neither because you didn't tell us your drupal version.

Comment: @NoSssweat oops, elementary mistake there on my part. I have revised my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at how the [web_widgets](https://www.drupal.org/project/web_widgets) module was making CSS/JS paths absolute and it looks like a valid solution is just to alter `$GLOBALS['base_path']` to add the URL of my site. An easy way to do this is with `url()`:

```
  $GLOBALS['base_path'] = url('', array(
    'absolute' => TRUE,
  ));
```